# How can I boolean the shape on the curve surface?

Tags: modifiers

I have some questions when I use boolean to hollow the groove on the surface.

First, I duplicate the texture and try to shrinkwrap on the surface, but some of them will distort while they snap on the surface. How can I fix it?

Then, the surface will disappear after I Boolean the surface with the object. I can't find what happened in this modeling process.

There are some pictures below which can show the problem I meet.

1. The texture I want which I made beforehand.
   [image]
2. After I shrinkwrap in the surface, the shape will distort
   [image]
3. The surface disappear after I Boolean them with the shape
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: do u want it like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnhcI.jpg

Comment: @Chris yes!! how can I fix the problem that exists above?

Comment: You have to apply all the modifier before. And yes, then it is not non-destructive anymore, but I don’t know another way.